# Kivy in Qpython on Android device

Tags: android, python-3.x, kivy, qpython3

Mr Nooby Gonzales here

Using Qpython3 on Android, trying to import Kivy module.

Tried running the basic hello world program in snippets3 folder:

```
#-*-coding:utf8;-*-
#qpy:2
#qpy:kivy

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button

class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        # display a button with the text : Hello QPython 
        return Button(text='Hello QPython')

TestApp().run()
```

but python loading screen "catch an exception: restart app", then returns to editor.

Also tried to install module in pip, but need cyphon. Tried to install Cython but the below happened.

I'd appreciate any help or explanation, I've trawled all day for a solution.

Thanks

```
/data/data/org.qpython.qpy3/files/bin/qpython-android5.sh "/storage/emulated/0/qpython/scripts3/pip_console.py" && exit
pts3/pip_console.py" && exit      <
Input pip commands, ie: pip install {module}
-->pip install cython
Downloading/unpacking cython
  Running setup.py egg_info for package cython
    Unable to find pgen, not compiling formal grammar.

    warning: no files found matching '*.pyx' under directory 'Cython/Debugger/Tests'
    warning: no files found matching '*.pxd' under directory 'Cython/Debugger/Tests'
    warning: no files found matching '*.h' under directory 'Cython/Debugger/Tests'
    warning: no files found matching '*.pxd' under directory 'Cython/Utility'
Installing collected packages: cython
  Running setup.py install for cython
    Unable to find pgen, not compiling formal grammar.
    warning: build_py_2to3: byte-compiling is disabled, skipping.

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/storage/emulated/0/qpython/cache/pip-build/cython/setup.py", line 336, in <module>
        **setup_args
      File "/data/data/org.qpython.qpy3/files/lib/python3.2/site-packages/distutils/core.py", line 148, in setup
        dist.run_commands()
      File "/data/data/org.qpython.qpy3/files/lib/python3.2/site-packages/distutils/dist.py", line 917, in run_commands
        self.run_command(cmd)
      File "/data/data/org.qpython.qpy3/files/lib/python3.2/site-packages/distutils/dist.py", line 936, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "/data/data/org.qpython.qpy3/files/lib/python3.2/site-packages/setuptools-1.1-py3.2.egg/setuptools/command/install.py", line 53, in run
      File "/data/data/org.qpython.qpy3/files/lib/python3.2/site-packages/distutils/command/install.py", line 569, in run
        self.run_command('build')
      File "/data/data/org.qpython.qpy3/files/lib/python3.2/site-packages/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "/data/data/org.qpython.qpy3/files/lib/python3.2/site-packages/distutils/dist.py", line 936, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "/data/data/org.qpython.qpy3/files/lib/python3.2/site-packages/distutils/command/build.py", line 126, in run
        self.run_command(cmd_name)
      File "/data/data/org.qpython.qpy3/files/lib/python3.2/site-packages/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command
        self.distribution.run_command(command)
      File "/data/data/org.qpython.qpy3/files/lib/python3.2/site-packages/distutils/dist.py", line 936, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "/data/data/org.qpython.qpy3/files/lib/python3.2/site-packages/distutils/command/build_ext.py", line 345, in run
        self.build_extensions()
      File "/storage/emulated/0/qpython/cache/pip-build/cython/setup.py", line 217, in build_extensions
        from Cython.Build.Dependencies import cythonize
      File "/storage/emulated/0/qpython/cache/pip-build/cython/build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.2/Cython/Build/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
        from .Dependencies import cythonize
      File "/storage/emulated/0/qpython/cache/pip-build/cython/build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.2/Cython/Build/Dependencies.py", line 51, in <module>
        from ..Compiler.Main import Context, CompilationOptions, default_options
      File "/storage/emulated/0/qpython/cache/pip-build/cython/build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.2/Cython/Compiler/Main.py", line 27, in <module>
        from .StringEncoding import EncodedString
      File "/storage/emulated/0/qpython/cache/pip-build/cython/build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.2/Cython/Compiler/StringEncoding.py", line 54
        return EncodedString(u''.join(self.chars))
                               ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax
    Complete output from command /data/data/org.qpython.qpy3/files/bin/python-android5 -c "import setuptools;__file__='/storage/emulated/0/qpython/cache/pip-build/cython/setup.py';exec(compile(open(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /storage/emulated/0/qpython/cache/pip-z0g7yy-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed:
    running install

running build

running build_py

Unable to find pgen, not compiling formal grammar.

warning: build_py_2to3: byte-compiling is disabled, skipping.



running build_ext

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>

  File "/storage/emulated/0/qpython/cache/pip-build/cython/setup.py", line 336, in <module>

    **setup_args

  File "/data/data/org.qpython.qpy3/files/lib/python3.2/site-packages/distutils/core.py", line 148, in setup

    dist.run_commands()

  File "/data/data/org.qpython.qpy3/files/lib/python3.2/site-packages/distutils/dist.py", line 917, in run_commands

    self.run_command(cmd)

  File "/data/data/org.qpython.qpy3/files/lib/python3.2/site-packages/distutils/dist.py", line 936, in run_command

    cmd_obj.run()

  File "/data/data/org.qpython.qpy3/files/lib/python3.2/site-packages/setuptools-1.1-py3.2.egg/setuptools/command/install.py", line 53, in run

  File "/data/data/org.qpython.qpy3/files/lib/python3.2/site-packages/distutils/command/install.py", line 569, in run

    self.run_command('build')

  File "/data/data/org.qpython.qpy3/files/lib/python3.2/site-packages/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command

    self.distribution.run_command(command)

  File "/data/data/org.qpython.qpy3/files/lib/python3.2/site-packages/distutils/dist.py", line 936, in run_command

    cmd_obj.run()

  File "/data/data/org.qpython.qpy3/files/lib/python3.2/site-packages/distutils/command/build.py", line 126, in run

    self.run_command(cmd_name)

  File "/data/data/org.qpython.qpy3/files/lib/python3.2/site-packages/distutils/cmd.py", line 313, in run_command

    self.distribution.run_command(command)

  File "/data/data/org.qpython.qpy3/files/lib/python3.2/site-packages/distutils/dist.py", line 936, in run_command

    cmd_obj.run()

  File "/data/data/org.qpython.qpy3/files/lib/python3.2/site-packages/distutils/command/build_ext.py", line 345, in run

    self.build_extensions()

  File "/storage/emulated/0/qpython/cache/pip-build/cython/setup.py", line 217, in build_extensions

    from Cython.Build.Dependencies import cythonize

  File "/storage/emulated/0/qpython/cache/pip-build/cython/build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.2/Cython/Build/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>

    from .Dependencies import cythonize

  File "/storage/emulated/0/qpython/cache/pip-build/cython/build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.2/Cython/Build/Dependencies.py", line 51, in <module>

    from ..Compiler.Main import Context, CompilationOptions, default_options

  File "/storage/emulated/0/qpython/cache/pip-build/cython/build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.2/Cython/Compiler/Main.py", line 27, in <module>

    from .StringEncoding import EncodedString

  File "/storage/emulated/0/qpython/cache/pip-build/cython/build/lib.linux-armv7l-3.2/Cython/Compiler/StringEncoding.py", line 54

    return EncodedString(u''.join(self.chars))

                           ^

SyntaxError: invalid syntax

----------------------------------------
Command /data/data/org.qpython.qpy3/files/bin/python-android5 -c "import setuptools;__file__='/storage/emulated/0/qpython/cache/pip-build/cython/setup.py';exec(compile(open(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /storage/emulated/0/qpython/cache/pip-z0g7yy-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed failed with error code 1 in /storage/emulated/0/qpython/cache/pip-build/cython
Storing complete log in /sdcard/qpython/.pip/pip.log
-->


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uhNQT.png
```

Comment: I think Qpython3 just doesn't support Kivy.

Comment: Thanks. Hmmm. Vocates Kivy on the qpython site: http://wiki.qpython.org/doc/how-to-start/#gui-programming-with-kivy  Otherwise, can you recommend a good alternative for android GUI  compatible with Qpython3?

Comment: Also, from Kivy.org: ""Does Kivy support Python 3.x?¶

Yes! As of version 1.8.0 Kivy supports both Python >= 2.7 and Python >= 3.3 with the same codebase. Python 3 is also now supported by python-for-android.

However, be aware that while Kivy will run in Python 3.3+, our iOS build tools still require Python 2.7."

Comment: I don't know if QPython3 supports any gui mechanisms.

Comment: Kivy itself supports Python 3, as do its build tools for Android, but QPython is a different project with its own Android build that does not include Kivy with the Python 3 version.

Comment: Aha. thanks inclement. My object is to build an android app with python3 backend soley on my android device. Hopefully a way forward will materialise.

Comment: I hope to support this in [Pyonic interpreter](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.inclem.pyonicinterpreter3), but it will probably be some time before I get to the point of adding Kivy app support.